# Problem with indexing null values

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, isnull, query-performance

There is a table 'test' with ~ 10M records with field 'finish'.

```
select count(*) from test where finish is null;

 count
---------
 2485009
(1 row)
```

I'd like to create index to speed up queries like `select * from test where finish is null;`

Just for testing purpose the following indexes were created:

```
create index idx_t_0 on test(finish);
create index idx_t_1 on test((finish is null));
create index idx_t_2 on test(id) where finish is null;

gist=# set track_io_timing=on;                                                                                           [16/1920]
SET
gist=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from test where finish is null;
                                                         QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..2829257.75 rows=2493440 width=1249) (actual time=0.031..23673.804 rows=2485009 loops=1)
   Filter: (finish IS NULL)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 6686627
   Buffers: shared hit=129944 read=2606747
   I/O Timings: read=15210.163
 Planning time: 2.294 ms
 Execution time: 23847.759 ms
(7 rows)

gist=# set enable_seqscan=off;
SET
gist=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from test where finish is null;
                                                                QUERY PLAN

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=40312.83..2851483.71 rows=2493440 width=1249) (actual time=362.433..43436.427 rows=2485009 l
oops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (finish IS NULL)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3622568
   Heap Blocks: exact=14958 lossy=891618
   Buffers: shared read=913368
   I/O Timings: read=23970.878
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_t_2  (cost=0.00..39689.47 rows=2493440 width=0) (actual time=357.046..357.046 rows=2485009 loops=1
)
         Buffers: shared read=6792
         I/O Timings: read=50.203
 Planning time: 0.256 ms
 Execution time: 43688.891 ms
(11 rows)

gist=# set enable_bitmapscan = off;

SET
gist=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select * from test where finish is null;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------
 Index Scan using idx_t_1 on test  (cost=0.43..5670318.77 rows=2493440 width=1249) (actual time=2.049..14702.455 rows=2485009
 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((finish IS NULL) = true)
   Filter: (finish IS NULL)
   Buffers: shared read=913369
   I/O Timings: read=9994.256
 Planning time: 0.227 ms
 Execution time: 14875.190 ms
(7 rows)
```

**Config**

```
listen_addresses ='*'
port=5432

max_connections = 100
work_mem = 13107kB

shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB

maintenance_work_mem = 1GB

# checkpoint_timeout = 300
# checkpoint_warning = 300
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9

synchronous_commit = off

default_statistics_target = 500

random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2

wal_buffers = 16MB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 8GB

max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4

max_files_per_process=500
```

Comment: Maybe the statistics are off (`ANALYZE` the table), maybe `effective_cache_size` or `random_page_cost` are not configured correctly for your machine.

Comment: Was each test repeated multiple times, and from a cold cache?

Comment: @jjanes yes all tests were repeated several times ~ 10. No I do not have column finish_is_null, there is index which is named idx_finish_is_null. idx_t1 is built on expression (finish is null) magically its transformed to finish_is_null ))). Corrected.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe did vacuum analyze test after index creation. db server has 8G RAM, effective_cache_size 6G, random_page_cost 4 (HDD)

Comment: How did expected width change from 4 to 1255 between executions of the same query?

Comment: @jjanes I see the point will do tests again

Comment: @jjanes did it again and updated my question, I do not have any clue why width has changed during prev tests now its stable, still does not understand how to speed up query for is null condition (((

Comment: Your estimated widths are pretty wide (I assume the actual widths are as well, EXPLAIN ANALYZE doesn't divulge that) .  Do you really need to `select *`?  You should see what happens if you select only the columns you need, especially if doing so allows for index-only scans.

Comment: I'm having a hard time replicating either your planner choices, or your actual performance.  In my hands, it likes to use idx_t_2 with no special prodding via 'enable_* = off'.  But using that index takes the same amount of time as just doing the seq scan.  Do you have any other non-default settings?  Can you turn track_io_timing on, if is not already, then do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING OFF)?  The "analyze off" part is only necessary on machines/OS with slow user-land clocks.

Comment: @jjanes updated with io_timings + buffers and added config

Answer (score 1):

While I can see some strange planner behavior (where indexes with similar actual performance have dramatically different estimates), I can't replicate you main complaint that none of the indexes are not used.

If I create data which is ordered randomly:

```
create table test as select 
  x, 
  case when random()<0.25 then NULL else floor(random()*10000)::int end finish,
  repeat(md5(random()::text),20) as extra1, 
  repeat(md5(random()::text),20) as extra2
from generate_series(1,10000000) f(x);
```

Then it wants to use the index idx_t_2, preferring it by 3.7 fold over the sequential scan (which is actually way too much, as the actual execution time of these two plans, as well as ones using the other indexes, are all about equal).

But clearly your data is not randomly ordered.  Your index scan visits 1/3 as many buffers as the sequential scan does.  So clearly things with NULL values are clustered together in the table.  I recreate this with:

```
cluster test USING idx_t_1 ;
```

After doing that, I now get idx_t_1, rather than idx_t_2, as being the prefered way to execute your query.  And now with the data being clustered, it actually is faster than the seq scan by about 3 fold.  (The other two indexes are also now actually faster by about the same amount, but they both are estimated as being substantially more expensive than the seq scan.)

Without being able to reproduce what you see, it is hard to test what kind of parameter tweaks would fix the problem for you.  Perhaps you can suggest improvements to my data generation method which makes it reproduce your issue more closely?

Too also note, I also tried this under v13dev, and it shows the same pattern of results as v10 does.

Comment: I've tried your test on my db and the results are the same as yours. Query uses idx_t_2 and after clustering it uses idx_t_1. (